# Facebook comment app deleted - still active on website

Tags: facebook, comments

I used to manage a website but am no longer associated with it.  One of the features I implemented was a basic facebook comments application.  I created the app under my personal facebook account and managed it through developers.facebook.com.

I grew tired of receiving alerts whenever site visitors used the app to comment on an article so I deleted the application from my developers.facebook.com account.

The application still exists and operates as normal on the site.  I expected to see an error on the website.

I do not have administrative access to the site in order to remove the reference to application.  How can I completely "destroy" that application so that no site can reference it?

Comment: Were there any other administrators of the application?

Comment: Are you expecting the comments plugin to stop working because you deleted the app ID associated with the URLs? That's not the case - you just lose the ability to moderate the plugins via being an admin of the app ID, btu the comments plugin itself should still work. If the app was an actual app getting user authorisation and making API calls it should have stopped working, though (unless there was another admin, as Lix mentioned)

Comment: There are other admins of the app.  What impact does that have?  Can they kill the app by removing themselves, thus leaving no admin of the app?